# zIndex on Label

Tags: label, z-index, openlayers-3

Good morning,

I have a problem with the zindex of label in my marker. The ZIndex is respected with the marker type Image, but when I tried to add a label : Zindex is not applied on the label.
[image]

I used the code see below :

```
var features = [];
var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({zIndex: 1,image: new ol.style.Icon(({anchor: [0.5, 74],anchorXUnits: 'fraction',anchorYUnits: 'pixels',src: '/css/images/markerB.png'})),text: new ol.style.Text({font: '100 28px icon_set_1',text: "Z",offsetY: -52,fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'})})});
var lat = 3;
for(i=0;i<=0.5;i+=0.1) {
  var lon = 50 + i;
  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326',     'EPSG:3857'))});
  iconFeature.setStyle(myStyle);
  features.push(iconFeature);
}
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: features});vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource});map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

May be somebody can tell me, what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly,check this code,Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n4h77xnz/

```
  var features = [];
  var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      zIndex: 1,
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
          anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
          scale: 0.4,
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          src: 'icon.png'
      })),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '100 22px icon_set_1',
          text: "yz",
          offsetY: 22,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'black'
          })
      })
  });
  var lat = 3;
  for (i = 0; i <= 0.5; i += 0.1) {
      var lon = 50 + i;
      console.log(lon, lat);
      var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat, lon], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
      });
      iconFeature.setStyle(myStyle);
      features.push(iconFeature);
  }
  vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: features
  });
  vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
  });
  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

  map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize())
```

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote this answer if it is useful to you,Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem doesn't change. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/feg5um2t/( try a zoom out )

Comment: when zoomed out markers are over lapping ..so are labels...they shouldn,t overlap..that what u r trying to do...

Comment: When we zoomed out the image of markers respect the zindex level (automatic), but the label are always a zIndex superior :( The zIndex of each label should be the same that of the image

Comment: Problem resolved with the help of Alexandre Dubé on groups.google. Just in case for the reader future , mon error was due :i tried to modify the zIndex of style before to apply it on the marker and I tried to apply the same "variable" style on each marker

Comment: @Slayes Thanks for sharing the information...can u please create a fiddle or post modified code here..It might help lot of people..Thanks,